# How do I test if microbes have survived after dehydration?

Tags: bacteriology, lab-techniques, mycology, dehydration

I have a solution containing various bacteria and fungi.
My aim is to place solution on filter paper, and wait until it dries.
I then wish to test if the organisms have survived, either on the dried paper, or by rehydrating it (maybe placing the paper into water).
Can someone provide advice on the type of test(s) I should perform to achieve this result? 
Preferably the test would be easily sourced (purchase online?) and relatively cheap and easy as I am quite inexperienced in this area.
Thank you in advance for any advice that you can provide.

Comment: I think the fungi are not the problem, they are hardy. I used to revive yeast after freeze-drying the poor buggers. Anyway, good question +1

Comment: Is there some reason why blotting them onto culture media wouldn't work?

Comment: Hi @AliceD and thanks for the feedback. I'm now a bit more optimistic. Regards

Comment: Hi @Resonating it may. The drying part is nescessary, which I guess that media would support. Thanks very much for your help.